# Не работает Popover в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Не работает *Popover* в *bootstrap*

Опираясь на документацию *bootstrap* пытаюсь завести *Popover*: в *html*-файл вставляю тестовый код с сайта *bootstrap*:

Dismissible popover

но ничего не происходит, всплывашка по клику не срабатывает.

верстаю на препроцессоре *scss*

Подскажите, как правильно подключить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скопировал и подключил пример с сайта, всё работает.

```js
$(function() {
  // Включаем поповер везде, где есть атрибут data-toggle="popover"
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'focus'
  }); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
</div>
```